# Discord-py Как сделать так, чтобы бот мог выполнять пассивную работу и отвечать на вопросы одновременно?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Проблема в том, что бот делает какие-либо действия только с функцией on_message. При попытке сразу же стриггерить прогу на функции Hello и Wink бот молчит. Как мне сделать так, чтобы бот и выполнял пассивную работу, и отвечал на команды? Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
import json
import requests
import random
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        author = message.author
        word_list = ['test']

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send(f'Do not say that, {author.mention}!')
                    await message.author.edit(nick = 'BadWorder2009')

        messageattachments = message.attachments
        if len(messageattachments) > 0:
            for attachment in messageattachments:
                if attachment.filename.endswith(".dll"):
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send("No DLL's allowed!")
                elif attachment.filename.endswith('.exe'):
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send("No EXE's allowed!")
                else:
                    break

    @bot.command
    async def Hello():
        author = ctx.message.author
        Welcome = ['Welcome to the club,', 
        "I smell one of cum monsters... Wait! That's just",
        'You entered this server... But at what cost? Oh, sure. For 300 bucks. Hi,',
        'ave -',
        'Hello,',
        'into ',
        'And so it begins... Oh! Hello,']
        await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(Welcome)} {author.mention}!') 

        response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/hug')
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)

        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900) 
        embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) 
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    @bot.command()
    async def wink(ctx):
        author = ctx.message.author
        user = ctx.message.mentions[0]
        Winky = [' just winked to ',
        ' tried to hit on ']
        await ctx.send(f'{author.name}{random.choice(Winky)}{user.mention}!')
        response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/wink')
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)

        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900)
        embed.set_image(url = json_data['link'])
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

client = MyClient()
client.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша главная проблема в том, что в качестве основного бота вы используете класс `MyClient`, объектом которого является `discord.Client` - бот, который не умеет обрабатывать команды.

Да, в строке `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])` вы объявляете бота `commands.Bot`, который умеет обрабатывать команды, но по итогу не запускаете его.

*Для запуска бота, нужно вызвать у его объекта функцию `run(token)`. Эту функцию (в самом низу кода) вы вызываете только для бота из класса `MyClient`.

---

После того, как вы решите первую проблему, перед вами скорее всего встанет вторая:

В функции `on_message()` бот принимает абсолютно все сообщения, а вам нужно также обрабатывать команды. Как раз для таких случаев в `Discord API` есть функция `await bot.process_commands(message)`. Добавьте ее в начало функции обработки сообщений и тогда бот сначала будет проверять сообщение на предмет команды, а уже затем выполнять какие-то действия.